# Calling identical tables on different pages

Tags: excel, vba

I recorded a macro and to sort a table on one page it assigns a page name, I would like to set it as a variable so it would do the same thing on what ever active page it is on.

I have a named cell that reflects the page name and tried putting that in but kept getting errors.

Just trying to replace ("TRADE") with a variable that represents the active page

```
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("TRADE").ListObjects("Table4").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("TRADE").ListObjects("Table4").Sort.SortFields.Add _
        Key:=Range("Table4[[#All],[Column2]]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:= _
        xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("TRADE").ListObjects("Table4").Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("TRADE").ListObjects("Table6").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("TRADE").ListObjects("Table6").Sort.SortFields.Add _
        Key:=Range("Table6[[#All],[Column2]]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:= _
        xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("TRADE").ListObjects("Table6").Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    End Sub
```

Comment: Your table names `Table4` and `Table6` are hard-coded too. Won't that be an issue as well?

Comment: I have not tested that part yet but the pages are going to be identical and it seems like table names are unique to that page so hoping I will not have a problem with that part.

Comment: Yes after I tried it, It got an out of range or undifined error so good observation, any solution would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is untested but replace this ...

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("TRADE")
```

... with this ...

```
ActiveSheet
```

(When I say "untested", I mean ActiveSheet should exist within the context whether it works holistcally across all code you change is another story, it's just a caveat to my answer.)

Comment: I guess it was just a partial answer the table numbers are unique and cannot be changed to the same name on a different page, Any way to find and assign a variable to that also.

Comment: @Inoverhishead what if you prefix the table name on each sheet with the sheet name? If you do that, adjusting the logic is easy.

Comment: Can I conacate or whatever that is called inside of the " Table6 " so it would be something like "  "table6"  & "pagename" " as a varaible

Comment: @Inoverhishead yeah, as long g as you update each table on each sheet, you would then change your code to be instead of “Table4”, it be ActiveSheet.Name & “Table4”

Comment: ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table" & ActiveSheet.Name).Sort.SortFields.Add _
            Key:=Range("Table & ActiveSheet.Name[[#All],[Column2]]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:= _
            xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

Comment: @Inoverhishead ... you're getting there.  You need to close a quote though on that.  So something like this ... ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table" & ActiveSheet.Name).Sort.SortFields.Add _ Key:=Range("Table" & ActiveSheet.Name & "[[#All],[Column2]]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:= _ xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal ... whenever you inject variables into a string, it should be like this ... "This is the " & ActiveSheet.Name & " worksheet"

Comment: That part of the code is saying""  method  range of object ,,,   global failed

Comment: @Inoverhishead I made a typo and changed it, refresh and try again. If it still fails, send me the error.

Comment: Only in front of the Key:= range part of the code  it expected a list seperater or )

Comment: @Inoverhishead can you paste your code in here again?

Comment: @Inoverhishead I thought you might've been getting there cos you went quiet.  Well done, you're officially a VBA programmer.  :-)

Comment: Sub Macro6()
'
' Macro6 Macro
'

'
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table" & ActiveSheet.Name).Sort.SortFields.Clear
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table" & ActiveSheet.Name).Sort.SortFields.Add _
            Key:=Range("Table" & ActiveSheet.Name & "[[#All],[Column2]]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:= _
            xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        With ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table" & ActiveSheet.Name).Sort
            .Header = xlYes
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply

Comment: Not sure if it will help anyone but it was hard to go thru the name manger and pick out 6 tables for each sheet but started renaming them after the column they were in plus page name and made it a lot quicker to keep track of and name Column & page name

Answer (score 1):

The answer that Skin gave you is probably the best way to go, but here is an alternative one: replace the hard coded name with a variable, like so...

```
Dim wks As Worksheet
Set wks = ActiveSheet
```

You would then need to replace each instant of the worksheet name with `wks.Name`. Your code would look something like this:

```
Dim wks As Worksheet
Set wks = ActiveSheet

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(wks.Name).ListObjects("Table4").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(wks.Name).ListObjects("Table4").Sort.SortFields.Add _
        Key:=Range("Table4[[#All],[Column2]]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:= _
        xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(wks.Name).ListObjects("Table4").Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(wks.Name).ListObjects("Table6").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(wks.Name).ListObjects("Table6").Sort.SortFields.Add _
        Key:=Range("Table6[[#All],[Column2]]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:= _
        xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(wks.Name).ListObjects("Table6").Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

End Sub
```